# If I've uploaded my Django app on Heroku, what is the architectural structure?

Tags: django, heroku

Heroku instructs that gunicorn be used to start the server, but from my understanding, gunicorn is an interface/gateway.

Which web server is being used?

Why was it that I never had to configure any part of this when deploying on Heroku? I'm essentially curious what the architectural structure is of the typical Django app deployed on Heroku.

Comment: Why would you want to configure it? The whole point of Heroku is that it takes care of all that for you.

Comment: If you followed the tutorial then Gunicorn _is_ the webserver https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn http://gunicorn.org/

Comment: @DanielRoseman not that I wanted to configure it, but I became curious when I realized I didn't have to configure NGINX. So does Heroku essentially replace/handle the duties of the server?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku used to run nginx in front of your application but no longer does so. It's simpler this way, and easier to set up with less nginx-specific issues.

However, you lose things like the better caching, connection and static asset handling, and things like `X-Accel-Redirect` that way.

You can use a custom buildpack like [nginx-buildpack](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/nginx-buildpack) if you want more control over the setup. If you just want things like static asset caching, [Heroku recommends setting up a CDN](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-caching#enabling-http-caching) in front of your application.